# PhpStorm ERROR: Code analysis failed with exception: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: null

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-analysis

When I write a function, it gives an error, but when I cut and paste the same function, the error goes away. And when I commit the file, I get the error I specified in the image. Can anyone help with the solution to the problem?

Screenshots are available below.
[image: error image]

[image: IDE error]

Comment: Try disabling **Grazie** plugin and restart PhpStorm -- any better now?

Comment: Thank you the problem is fixed. Is there anything I can do for you? @LazyOne

Answer (score 0):

Please disable bundled **Grazie** plug, restart PhpStorm and check again -- any better?

If it is then it might be [IDEA-275168](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275168) ticket (that seems to somehow only affects Turkish users).